# Combinatorics, number of sequences with defined start.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

First-time poster. Here are some questions I am given that I am to solve. The pool of numbers is 20 in all questions. :)

0. How many different sequences of at least one and up to 4 numbers exist? The same
   the number can occur several times in the sequence. Two sequences of the same numbers in
   different order is considered different.
1. How many different sequences of 4 numbers start with 1, taken from a pool of 20 numbers?
2. How many sequences contain the number one, starting with any number between 1-20?
3. How many sequences can be made with a length of four numbers from 1-20?

Please show me how you work/what formula as I have many more tasks to do, but unsure of the formula I should use:)

Edit:
Imagine there are only twenty numbers, 1-20. There are more but for simplicity there are only twenty to be considred as 20 is easier to handle.

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what you have attempted so far?

Comment: To be honest i am very blank as to what i am supposed to do. I've tried 20^3 but it just doesnt seem right...

Comment: Don't just depend on somebody handing you a magic formula.  Think about what the problem(s) are asking.  In this case, I don't even think the questions are clear.  Are repetitions allowed?  Note that in many cases, such as your second question, it is far easier to count the bad sequences (which then gives you the count of the good sequences since the total number is easy to find).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @lulu . Im trying to go through my book, this is a new subject so I'm not sure what to do, thats why im asking. How would you go through caluclating the bad sequences? That sequence is also only four numbers long.

Comment: The answer $20^3$ is correct for the first question if repetition is permitted.  You should add your attempts to the question itself and clarify the conditions.  For instance, is repetition of numbers permitted?

Comment: If a sequence does not contain the number $1$, how many choices do you have for each entry in the sequence?

Comment: thank you @N.F.Taussig. Repitition is not specified, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Please edit your post to include all the relevant information.

Comment: If repetitions are banned, then $20^3$ is wrong.  What would the answer to the first part be if the length were only $2$ instead of $4$?

Comment: For question 0?

Comment: Yes. $\quad$ $\quad$

Comment: Sequence of 1 number = 20, sequence of 2 numbers = 20^2, sequence of 3= 20^3, sequence of 4 numbers = 20^4 is what i think right now. Repitions banned, maybe im thinking sequence not banned?

Comment: sorry @lulu, this is my first time ever with these types of questions.

Comment: Please list the $20$ sequences of length $2$ (counting that initial $1$).   Since they all begin with $1$, you can just list the second term.

Comment: P(n,r)=n!/(n−r)!=?, thought maybe this would work, im trying to wrap my head around it and keep thinking of this

Comment: I suggest:  Start with simpler problems.  Problems for which you can easily list the various cases.  Of course the idea is to do the counting without listing everything out, but while learning the stuff it is great if you can also do it by writing it all out.  Best way to test the patterns you think you have found.

Comment: @lulu. thanks i will try that:)

Comment: My comment is different from, but consistent with the comment of @lulu.  I have found that when trying to learn from a Math book, it is important to [1] Insist that the book feature a large number of exercises, since (for me) $80\%$ of my learning takes place attacking the exercises, rather than reading the text/theorems.  ...see next comment.

Comment: [2] Go slow and do not skip any exercises.  One at a time, for any exercise that you are not sure of, post that exercise as a separate question to a teacher or Math forum, and be very sure that you understand the solution given for that exercise, before you move on.  The point here is that learning is cumulative, so that if you don't thoroughly understand the solution to an earlier problem, you will inevitably get into trouble with the later problems.  Further, learning must include stretching your intuition, or again, you will get into trouble.

Comment: You should approach Math as if it was a foreign language.  You are trying to force yourself into thinking in terms of the foreign language.  It analogizes to a tourist with a Berlitz book translating what they hear and then speak, one word at a time versus someone fluent in the foreign language.